# Generate elements of a tensor based on a vector in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

How can you generate a numpy tensor that iterates over the different values of a vector? For example if I want in the following formula:

```
rotation_mats=numpy.array([numpy.cos(theta),0,numpy.sin(theta)])
```

All the thetas be replaced by a range from `[0,pi/2]` and the outcome is a matrix such as following:

```
[[1,0,0],
 [. . .],
 [0,0,1]]
```

What is the easiest way of doing it?

Comment: So your `rotation_mats` tensor is a 2D array and `numpy.cos(theta)`, `0` and `numpy.sin(theta)` represents columns of arbitrary size?

Comment: No they are going to be the same size at the end. I believe it is in the question itself where I say what the output looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
theta = numpy.arange(0, numpy.pi/2, 0.01) # You can control the step, of course
result = numpy.array([numpy.cos(theta),
                      numpy.zeros(len(theta)),
                      numpy.sin(theta)]
                     ).T
```

Comment: Hmm an easy solution that does work. Just out of curiosity is there a smarter way?

Comment: @A2B What do you mean by 'smarter'?

Comment: As in something that would work in a symbolic way. Something like this is a pattern of each element and here are the thetas.

Answer (score 2):

playing with shape and trigonometry:

```
a=linspace(0,pi/2,10).reshape(-1,1)
rotmats=sin(hstack((a+pi/2,0*a,a)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Abusing [`trigonometry`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Sine_Squared_plus_Cosine_Squared) and [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), here's a one-liner for fun -

```
>>> np.sqrt(np.abs(np.cos(np.linspace(0,np.pi/2,10))[:,None]**[2,0,2]+[0,-1,-1]))
array([[ 1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ],
       [ 0.9848,  0.    ,  0.1736],
       [ 0.9397,  0.    ,  0.342 ],
       [ 0.866 ,  0.    ,  0.5   ],
       [ 0.766 ,  0.    ,  0.6428],
       [ 0.6428,  0.    ,  0.766 ],
       [ 0.5   ,  0.    ,  0.866 ],
       [ 0.342 ,  0.    ,  0.9397],
       [ 0.1736,  0.    ,  0.9848],
       [ 0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ]])
```